# How can ichimoku lines values ​be obtained with the pandas_ta library in Python?

Tags: python, pandas-ta

Anyone familiar with the pandas_ta library?
I use the following code to get ichimoku values:

```
ichi = ta.ichimoku(df['high'], df['low'], df['close'], include_chikou=True)
```

Ichi type should be data frame but the output is a 2-member tuple.
Does anyone know where the problem comes from?

Answer (score 1):

The ichimoku function returns 2 dataframes. The first df with values up until the current candle and one for the forward looking part of the cloud.

Comment: Thank youI realized. I was able to access data frames using ichi [0] or ichi [1].

Answer (score 0):

Since a tuple is returned, you can use this code

```
def add_ichi(self, tenkan: int = 9, kijun: int = 26, senkou: int = 52, offset: int = 26) -> None:
        df_ichi = ta.ichimoku(self.df["high"], self.df["low"], self.df["close"], tenkan=tenkan, kijun=kijun, senkou=senkou, offset=offset)
        df_ichi[0].columns = ["spanA", "spanB", "tenkan_sen", "kijun_sen", "chikou_span"]
        df_ichi[1].columns = ["spanA_future", "spanB_future"]
        self.df["spanA_future"] = df_ichi[1]["spanA_future"]
        self.df["spanB_future"] = df_ichi[1]["spanB_future"]
```

For example, `df_ichi[1]["spanA_future"]` - we move the data from tuple [1] to the Pandas dataframe column `df["spanA_future"]`